# Android SDK player automation

Tags: android, automation, sdk

I am automation the android SDK player. My Video player is Android SDK player not HTML5 or Flash. How can we perform the below scenarios on Android SDK player.

1. Subtitle detection inside the video player - Presence of a subtitle.
2. Lip sync/reading.
3. How to get the metadata or thumbnail of a video player.
4. How to detect a blank or black screen.

Can we automate above scenarios for Android SDK player? I am using the Appium for mobile app automation. Do we have any external lib/tool/jar available which will support to appium to perform above scenarios? Any JavaScript actions?